# How can I count and display my recursive steps in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, counter

I am trying to count how many times my program goes through my recursive statement and gives me my result. This is the code:

```
def days(amt):
    day = 0
    new = (amt*.05) + amt - 10

    if amt == 0:
        return 0

    elif amt == '':
        return

    elif new >= 0 and new <= 1000:
        day += 1
        return days(new)

print("In {} days, you'll have {}".format(day,new))
```

So when you call the function `days(100)`, it calculates that it takes 15 days to reach new amount which less than 0 or greater than 1000 (and then it stops bc it satisfies the second elif condition).

So I want my output to look like this `In 15 days, you'll have -7.892...`.

My problem is no matter where I place the counter, it doesn't count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To persist the count you need to either use some global variable or use a parameter to do the counting then return both the count and the amt:

```
def days(amt, day=1):
    new = (amt * .05) + amt - 10

    if amt == 0:
        return day, 0

    elif 0 <= new <= 1000:
        return days(new, day + 1)
    return  day, new
```

Which gives you:

```
In [2]: print("In {} days, you'll have {}".format(*days(100)))
In 15 days, you'll have -7.89281794114
```

You cannot set  `day = 0` anywhere in the function as every call is going to reset it to 0. I also removes `elif amt == ''` as I cannot see how a function that takes an int/float should ever equal to an empty string.

Comment: The day +=1 under the elif statement ends up doubling the number of days. So you can take that out and leave the day + 1 in the recursive call. Otherwise, perfect! Thanks!

Comment: Make day = 1 in the function call.

Comment: Yep, forgot I had the +=

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!